# eosjs-ecc in other languages?

Tags: eosjs, android, ios

I'm looking for a way to do this
https://github.com/EOS-Nation/eos-encrypt/blob/master/examples/encrypt-multiple-keys.ts

it Java and Swift. Did anyone try to port it?

Comment: Working on a C#-Version from time to time but havn't heard of a Java or Swift-Version of the ECC. Do it yourself! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the links:

Ecc in Swift : https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio-swift-ecc

Ecc in Java : https://github.com/EOSTribe/java-ecc/tree/master/app/src/main/java/io/plactal/ecc